# Sveltekit Use:Enhance or Binding data to child component

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I created a child component phonetextbox

[image: phonetextbox child component]

and use it in my parent component

[image: phonetextbox used in parent component]

the phone textbox has a default value of (111)-111-1111 i set it in the +page.server.js

the form has a Use:Enhance to prevent reload the page. when i tried to submit the button
the phonetextbox is empty.

[image: value after submitting the form]

but i display the value below the textbox it has the value i want.

i dont know if the cause of this is the binding part but the other input works fine.

#note the other inputs is not a child component is just a simple input type text. and i tried setting the default value inside the child component phonetextbox its still the same.

i want to bind the default value to my child component phonetextbox when ever the form is submitted

Comment: Do *not* screenshot code, it's inaccessible and can't be copied. Just insert it as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). If you want to highlight a particular spot, use comments in the code.

Comment: Also, fix your `label` accessibility warnings, it's not that difficult; just make the input a child of the `label` or use [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/for). (If an input is part of a component you can get false positives, in that case ignoring the warning is required.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.